# Taking the Colombo-Galle train while on a cruise ship stop

Tags: trains, sri-lanka

I will be on a Round-the-World cruise, calling Colombo 18th March. The ship arrives at 7 a.m. and leaves at 10 p.m.

I hope to take the train from Colombo Fort at 10.30 a.m., arriving in Galle at 12.45 p.m., and return at 2.42 p.m., arriving back in Colombo at 5.11 p.m. Would that be too risky?

Comment: What do the cruise company’s T&C say about its boarding cut-off time? Is the 2:42pm train back the only one that day? What one person defines as ‘too risky’ might be acceptable to someone else.

Comment: @Traveller You can drive from Galle to Colombo in under two hours (traffic permitting), so taking a taxi is always a backup option.  But it still sounds like an awfully rushed itinerary, why not just enjoy Colombo's sights for the day?

Comment: Yes, I have concluded with taking a commuter train to Kalutara and back instead, and then join one of the ship's excursions in Colombo. I just want to try train riding in Sri Lanka as well - I so far have travelled by train in 79 countries. But thank you, for answering so quickly!

Comment: Cruise ships seems to dock at walking distance from city center, so it seems doable. Tip: ask some local crew members.